# LocalConnection and iframes

Tags: flash, actionscript, iframe, localconnection

I'm trying get LocalConnection to work between two swf's placed within two different IFRAMES.
I've worked with LocalConnection often without too much trouble. But this time --i suspect because of the iframes--i can't get it to work.

Anybody experience the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is allowed. The SWFs are all sandboxed to the same flash player instance. You just need to insure that your security configuration is correct. Take a look at the LiveDocs for [LocalConnection's allowDomain function](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html#allowDomain()).

Answer (score 0):

... Ok, tried this in many different ways, but it seems that
Communication between iframes using LocalConnections is not allowed.

Comment: Make sure that you are prefixing the the connection name used in both the connect and send functions with an underscore (example: _foo). You'll also need to specifiy the wildcard "*" to allow calls from all domains.

Comment: yowsa, I spent a long time on this too - I had tried absolutely everything mentioned everywhere EXCEPT the underscore convention. Ugh.